# Try with resource (PreparedStatements)

Tags: java

So I was wondering which method is prefered, I will be reading each line from a file and storing it into onto my database. I will have a lot of prepared statements as I will be doing a lof of selects (checking if entry exists to grab an id value from table), or inserts when it doesn't exist. These kind of sql will be performed like 5 times as I will be inserting into 5 different tables.

So I wasn't sure if it's ok to create a lot of prepared statements as I will be leaving a lot of opened connections, however most statements will be used while I'm reading from the file. Or because I have a lot of preparedstatements create them inside the while loop and have them in their own try resource block so I don't leave too many opened connections?

```
try {PreparedStatement stmt1 = connection.PrepareStatement(Sql);
     PreparedStatement stmt2 = connection.PrepareStatement(Sql);
     PreparedStatement stmt3 = connection.PrepareStatement(Sql);
     PreparedStatement stmt4 = connection.PrepareStatement(Sql);
     etc . . . )
     while read line from file {
           //etc
     }
}
```

Or is this prefered:

```
while read line from file {
     try {PreparedStatement stmt1 = connection.PrepareStatement(Sql);
          PreparedStatement stmt2 = connection.PrepareStatement(Sql))
          // stmt1.setint(1, blah)
          // stmt1.execute()
          //etc
     }

     try {PreparedStatement stmt3 = connection.PrepareStatement(Sql);
          PreparedStatement stmt4 = connection.PrepareStatement(Sql))
          // stmt1.setint(2, blah)
          // stmt1.execute()
          //etc
     }
}
```

Comment: You only have a single `connection` in the above code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. There is no problem for `connection` in either way as you are using the same connection object.
2. However, the second way is not recommended at all because you will be compiling the same SQLs again and again. A sheer waste of computing power and unnecessary pressure on garbage collection!

Answer (score 1):

I would use the first variant. The second one openes and closes the `PreparedStatement` for each line, which will be slower than leaving them open all the time, especially if you have a lot of lines to process. Preparing the statement itsself is also not a cheap action.